# Making unsigned integer underflow throw an exception

Tags: c++

I understand that there are applications in which using unsigned integer over/underflow is a good way to get cheap modular arithmetic.

In my code, I use `uint` exclusively for indices to containers, so I *never* want this behaviour.

1. Is this a bad idea? Should I be using `int` everywhere instead? I do have to do some unsavoury things to get a for loop to count down to 0.
2. Is there a commonly used implementation of a less unsafe unsigned integer type? Something that throws an exception?
3. Do compilers (for me gcc, clang) provide a mechanism for less unsafe behaviour in the given compilation unit?

Comment: Related to your problem, but doesn't answer it, I would suggest avoiding indexes whenever possible. Use iterators instead if you can. Or if not possible then for containers that uses indexes (basically only `std::vector` and `std::deque`) use the `at` function instead as it will throw an exception when indexing out of bounds. And when you need to iterate over a container, you can use [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) or [range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead of indexes.

Comment: There is no such thing as unsigned integer overflow / underflow in C++ and C. Unsigned integers implement arithmetic on `Z mod 2^BumBit` and can thus represent any whole number by choosing the representative of its equivalence class that is in `[0, 2^NumBit)`. If that's not what you want, e.g. because -1 and 2^64-1 don't mean the same thing in your program, use signed integers.

Comment: So yes, you should be using signed integers for your indices. Ib4 "but the standard library uses unsigned too": Several prominent members of the committee admitted that that was a bad idea and advocate signed integers too, see e.g. https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything 9:50, 42:40, 1:02:50

Comment: @BaummitAugen: But not all of them. I for one think that having the full range available is absolutely crucial. I understand that this isn't appropriate in _all_ scenarios (e.g. the OP's) but, honestly, wasting an an entire power of two just for a "-1" sentinel value? Big meh.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: lol @ "BumBit"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "BumBit" Rats. :/ Concerning your point: If you need the extra bit, because you have an array of `char` or `bool` or smth. like that that takes more than half of total RAM on a 32 bit system, you gotta do what you gotta do. Such a thing never happened in any code I saw so far though.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: Meh true. I suppose it's the principle of the thing ;lp Still, I'd rather be able to choose. I'm glad the stdlib uses unsigneds. There'd be no way to "undo" a choice to use signeds instead, and bam your containers are artificially limited to only 50% of your available memory space. And for what? stdlib is a very well tested black box, from our perspective. When do we directly use array indexes with the stdlib? Hopefully (almost) never. So, if anything, I'd say that people might want to use signed in their own code but that the stdlib _definitely_ should use unsigneds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a terminology quibble: there is no such thing as unsigned integer underflow, precisely *because* of the way they *wrap around* (using modulo arithmetic), which is probably the phrase you meant.

Second, is this a common scenario to be in? Yes, it is a bit. You're not the only one doing "unsavoury things" with loops for reverse counting, and I bet there are a ton of bugs out there where people *haven't* done "unsavoury things" and, as a result, their code has an unsavoury infinite loop hidden in it. Mind you, I'm not sure I'd go so far as to call unsigneds "unsafe" as a result; like anything, they are the right tool for a subset of infinite possible jobs, and within that subset they perfectly safe.

There is debate over whether unsigned integers should be used for array indexes at all. Some standard committee members believe that their use in the standard library was a mistake; I know that several members of the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) community here on Stack Overflow also hate `unsigned` values and wish they'd go away.

Personally I think having access to the full range of the integer by default is absolutely crucial (and losing that is not worth it for a single "-1" sentinel value or whatever), so I think that — while you're not alone in this requirement, and it's a sensible requirement — using unsigned array indexes by default is a good thing. (And what the heck is a negative array index? Semantics, people!)

But that doesn't help you in this scenario. So, what can you do about it? No, there's no trapping unsigned integer implementation (at least, not one that I'm aware of, let alone widespread) because that would literally violate the rules of the type as defined by C++: it would introduce well-defined underflow/overflow semantics to a type for which underflow/overflow shouldn't even be possible.

You will have to use signed integers and check for "logical underflow" (i.e. going out of *your* desired range, say -1) yourself. You could wrap this behaviour in a class.

I suppose you *could* actually just wrap an unsigned integer while you're at it, adding some extra logic to `operator--` and `operator-=` to detect a wrap-around and throw.

But I guess my point is that, whatever you do, it's going to be in your "code space" and thus subject to decreased performance. You can't eke out this behaviour from the platform itself.

Comment: +uno for the whole lot - in particular, they can take my `unsigned`s when they - well, you know the rest.